# How to convert bytes arrays type of double from Java Android to image in Matlab?

Tags: java, android, image, matlab, sockets

I am currently working on online SfM and I need to send stream of Images from Android phone to Matlab. I've managed to send bytes of data to Matlab from Android through TCP/IP Socket programming but I am unable to convert it to image. I expect that the image would be saved in the directory or if it's possible to be directly consumed by the SfM pipeline as described on this link: [Structure from Motion from two views](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/structure-from-motion-from-two-views.html). I tried to decode it with java as described here:[how to convert a cell array into an image?](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/157391-how-to-convert-a-cell-array-into-an-image%20how%20to%20convert%20a%20cell%20array%20into%20an%20image?), but it didn't work as well. I got an error "Struct contents reference from a non-struct array object." on "height = jimage.getHeight;". Do you know how to fix this problem? Or do you know how to do this correctly in Matlab?

This is my Java Code inside `AsyncTask` class in `doInBackground` method:

```
socket = new Socket();
SocketAddress socketAddress = new InetSocketAddress(host, port);
socket.connect(socketAddress, 2000);

final DataOutputStream dataOutputStream;

final BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
int count = data[0].length;

dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

dataOutputStream.writeInt(count);
dataOutputStream.flush();

out.write(data[0], 0, count);

out.flush();
```

This is my Matlab code:

```
t = tcpip('0.0.0.0', 8889, 'NetworkRole', 'Server');
set(t,'InputBufferSize', 3000000);
set(t,'Timeout', 30);
disp('Waiting Connection...');
fopen(t);

while(1) 
 if (t.BytesAvailable > 0)
  disp('Connection succeed.');
  rawData = fread(t,t.BytesAvailable);
  whos rawData; 
  jimage = javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(java.io.ByteArrayInputStream(rawData));
  height = jimage.getHeight;
  width = jimage.getWidth;
  pixels = reshape(typecast(jimage.getData.getDataStorage, 'uint8'), [3,width,height]);
  img = cat(3, ...
  transpose(reshape(pixels(3,:,:), [width,height])), ...
  transpose(reshape(pixels(2,:,:), [width,height])), ...
  transpose(reshape(pixels(1,:,:), [width,height])));
  imshow(img);
end
end
fclose(t);
```

This is the sample of data that I get from "whos rawData":

```
Size: 390964x1           
Bytes: 3127712  
Class: double
```

Comment: `bytes arrays type of double`. Please start your post with an example of such an array. I have no idea where you are talking about.

Comment: `data[0]` What is `data`? What does it contain? Please show all in code. Edit your post.

Comment: online SfM`? What is that?